# Not able pass the data from one view to another in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uiactionsheet

I have included UIActionSheet in my program.It contains 2 button say A and B. When a user clicks on the A button it goes to another view. In that view, it contains 3 text field.So in the mainviewcontroller, I am assigning the values to these textfield. I will paste the code below :-

In MainViewController.m

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex 
  {
         AnotherViewController *A = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];

          if (buttonIndex == 1) 
          {

              A.newtask = name;
              A.newsubtask = sub1;
              A.newduedate = dateName;
              A.newtime = timeName;


     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];                                                                    

     UpdateViewController   *viewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"update"];

     [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];


          }
   }
```

And in AnotherViewcontroller.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {

              task_update.text = newtask;
              subtask_update.text =newsubtask;
              duedate_update.text = newduedate;
              time_update.text = newtime;

           NSLog(@"The task is :%@",newtask);
              [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

The problem is I am getting null value in the newtask. Can anyone please tell me the solution. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take Global Variables in AppDelegate Class. Like
AppDelegate .h

```
NSString *newtask,*newsubtask,*newduedate,*newtime;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *newtask,*newsubtask,*newduedate,*newtime;
```

AppDelegate. m

```
@synthesize newtask,newsubtask,newduedate,newtime;
```

MainViewController.h

## import "AppDelegate"

```
{
AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
```

MainViewController.m

```
    (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex 
      {
appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
             AnotherViewController *A = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];
    
              if (buttonIndex == 1) 
              {
    
                  appDelegate.newtask = name;
                  appDelegate.newsubtask = sub1;
                  appDelegate.newduedate = dateName;
                  appDelegate.newtime = timeName;
    
    
         UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];                                                                    
    
         UpdateViewController   *viewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"update"];
    
         [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    
    
              }
       }
```

AnotherViewcontroller.h

## import "AppDelegate"

```
{
AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
```

AnotherViewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
   {
    appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

              task_update.text = appDelegate.newtask;
              subtask_update.text =appDelegate.newsubtask;
              duedate_update.text = appDelegate.newduedate;
              time_update.text = appDelegate.newtime;

           NSLog(@"The task is :%@",newtask);
              [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Comment: :No still I am getting null value in the newtask.. :(

Comment: See update code in Another View Controller                    appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; Add this line view did load

Comment: :Thank you so much..I got it.. :)